# Completing the sequence, is answer $98$ or $99$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In this sequence, what is the formula or series being followed?

I framed a formula:
$a^2 - ((a-b) * 2)$ 
Which derives to $98$.

But it also appears like they are multiplying a and b and adding a odd number sequence to it..
$a \times b$ added with odd number starting from $1$. 
$6+1=7$
$20+3=23$
$42+5=47$
$72+7=79$
So for $10$ and $9$ it will be $90+9$.

Which is correct?

[image]

Comment: Your $99$  is reasonable.  So is your $98$. Nice example!

Comment: Note that in all cases, $a-b=1$, so you could have just said $a^2-2$. \ Or it could be $a*b+b-1$, then the answer is $98$ again. But these sorts of problems are ill-defined at best - there are often multiple possible answers.

Comment: I hate this site.. it's full of downvoters.. downvote without giving reasons

Comment: My *guess* is that $98$ is intended.  (That way the function is at least space-homogeneous. <g>)  But as others have pointed out, there's really no way to know for sure. ¶ And geniuses will generally be bored by this kind of exercise.

Comment: If you want to know why your post is downvoted, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/sequences-and-series/info).

Comment: It seems to not depend on $b$ at all. It looks a lot like $a^2-2$